# Response too large to return even when allow large results is true

Tags: google-bigquery

Bigquery returns an error "Results too large to return" even when I have toggled "Allow Large Results".  My query looks like so:

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM table_1
WHERE a IN (SELECT a FROM table_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

When I re-organized the query to use a JOIN in place of a subquery the error went away.  My new query looks like so:

```
SELECT table_1.a as a, b, c
FROM table_1
JOIN EACH table_2
ON table_1.a = table_2.a
```

I suspect the problem was my use of a subquery (which was bad SQL anyways).

Comment: Exactly! The "results too large" came from the subquery - and JOIN EACH fixed that problem.

Comment: Your original query was not "bad SQL", it is a valid semijoin SQL, but IN clause doesn't support EACH qualifier the same way JOIN clause does.